# Service Task running without starting a process

Tags: bpmn, camunda

In my process, I have a service task(which is calling a method of a java class) running in loop after a certain interval of time. But before I go to tasklist and start the process I can see in the console that my process is running as the method is being called. The method has simple sysout statements. Is it because of the camunda internal architecture? or I have not configured properly?

Comment: Please add the process model to your problem description.

Comment: (start event) ---->(service task)(in a loop)


^workflow is as simple as this

Comment: Okay, then try to debug what starts the process instance. Unless the start event is a timer, the process engine won't start your process by itself.

Comment: Any timer events or async task involved? Those wont work automatically if you have no jobExecutor configured.

Comment: no start event is a simple start event. not a timer.

Comment: yes! i needed help in that.. What is actually triggering the service task?